# Javascript, assign value from .find or else 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to assign a value from `.find` with `Javascript`:

```
car.km = (my_cars.find(function (obj) { return obj.car_id === car.id }).drove) || 0)
```

It fails if there's no car_id matching with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'drove' of undefined
```

But I'm trying to use `|| 0` so `0` would be chosen if there's no `.drove`.
But doesn't work, how to do it?

Comment: Share the JSON `my_cars`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite your code as:

```
car.km = (
  my_cars.find(function(obj) {
    return obj.car_id === car.id;
  }) || { drove: 0 }
).drove
```

In this code, if `find` does not see any matching car id, it will return `undefined`. And when you get `undefined` from `find` function, then with the help of `||` operator you can return a `car` like object with a single property `drove` and call `.drove` at last.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if `find` didn't find anything, you are checking if the attribute `drove`on the result of `find` is null.

I think the most readable would be to store the result of find in a variable and do it in 2 lines.

```
let car = my_cars.find(function (obj) { return obj.car_id === car.id });
car.km = car ? car.drove : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code to:

```
var car = my_cars.find(function (obj) { return obj.car_id === car.id });
car.km = car ? car.drove : 0;
```

This is because `my_cars.find(function (obj) { return obj.car_id === car.id })` may give you `undefined` if no match found so it is recommended to assign the result of `find` into a variable before accessing the property `drove`.